# const reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

When I have a const reference to a pointer, how come I am able to change the value of the object the pointer points to, does the const means in this example,
address stored in pointer cannot be changed as the reference is a const.
but we can change the value of the object the pointer points through the reference

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int n = 5;
    int *ptr = &n;
    const auto &refOfPtr = ptr; 
    *refOfPtr = 10;
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    
}
```

```
Output : 10
```

Comment: That's because you have a reference to const pointer to non-const object. `const` qualifier in C++ is not transitive. If you want to make everything const, then you'll need to repeat `const` qualifier on each level of indirection: `int const * const &` Also note that usually `const` qualifier applies to something on the left side of it.

Comment: i think you can change the value of the const pointer because youre declaring the address of the pointer as const and not the actual value it references to.

Comment: you cannot change the address of the pointer, since its declared const, but the const declaration doesnt care about the variable its pointed to. That is why you are able to change the value. Though i doubt that the program will run.... Does it run as its expected to?

Comment: The opposite @Shreeyash - you can change the pointed-to value, but you cannot change the pointer itself.

Comment: Strongly related: [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?_](/q/1143262/4850040)

Comment: With your code, what you can't do is: `refOfPtr = &other_pointer;`

Comment: Your code never attempts to change the pointer.

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha You'll never be able to change the address of *any* variable ;-). You mean you cannot change the *value* of the pointer. There are three distinct values here:

Comment: (1) The *address* of the variable `ptr` (which is constant like the addresses of all other variables (think of variable names as aliases for specific addresses where objects reside)); (2) The *value* of the variable, which happens to be an address; (3) The value of the object residing at the address stored in the pointer ("pointee").

Comment: @user7860670 Re "usually const qualifier applies to something on the left side of it": That's exactly backwards and would linguistically awkward. `const` makes const what comes immediately after it -- that is to the right, not to the left. Just take the most simple definition: There *is* nothing to the left of `const int i;`. And `const int *p;` vs. `int *const p;`: The first one makes the int const, the second one p.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica When there is nothing on the left of `const` is an exception from the general rule and *the only* situation when `const` applies to something on the right of it. In my first comment, in `int const * const &` it always applies to stuff of the left, first `const` applies to `int`, not to pointer, second `const` applies to pointer, not to reference. `int *const p;` does not make `p` const, it makes `int *` const

Comment: `const` is **not** transitive.  What you have looks like this to the compiler (pseudo-code): `(int mutable (* const)) & refOfPtr = ptr;` where `mutable` and `const` are post-fix qualifiers and modify the thing to their immediate left.

Comment: @user7860670 Can you explain how after `int *const p;`, `p`  is not constant?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I only wrote that `const` does not apply to `p`, it applies to type declaration to the left. And it works like this regardless of presence of `p` on the right, for example you may write `static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int * const, decltype(p)>);` and `const` will still apply to stuff to the left of it. Your statement "const makes const what comes immediately after it -- that is to the right, not to the left." is simply not true. If it was indeed true then for example `const int *` and `int const *` would define different types.

Comment: @user7860670 Whatever is to the left is irrelevant (and not affected by the `const` at all! The result of dereferencing is not const): ***`p`*** is constant, which is expressed by putting  `const` in front of it. Regarding your cast: As you may remember from K&R: Types used in type casts mimic declarations where there is, perhaps astonishingly, a unique location where the grammar would permit an identifier. And lo and behold: That place would be *to the right* of the const, not to the left, which would be utterly weird and unintuitive.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Alright, if you insist that `const` applies to something to the right of it, then you also insist that `const int *` and `int const *` declarations define different types, right?

Comment: @user7860670 In both cases it applies to the result of the dereferencing operator. Whether the const is an int or the int is a const is considered equivalent by the language, which is fine by me. By the way, your example does not need a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a const reference to the pointer, so you can't change where it points.  I.e. the type of `refOfPtr` is `int * const &`, a reference to a const pointer to (mutable) integer.

But it points to a mutable object, so you can change the content of that object through this pointer.